# Proto3 формирование oneof

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

Есть proto файл

```
message Update {
    string AdminToken = 1;
    string Type = 2;
    string Hash = 3;
    oneof Value {
        string Name = 4;
        int64 Permission = 5;
        string Address = 6;
    }
}
```

Я пробую сформировать данные для отправки на сервер:

```
ss := &pb.Update{Value: &pb.Update_Name{Name: "asd"}, &pb.Update_Address{Address: "s"}, &pb.Update_Permission{Permission: 12}}
```

Надо нормально описать все три параметра в одну структуру. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Надо нормально описать все три параметра в одну структуру. Как это сделать?

Ваш вопрос не соотноситься с декларацией сообщения, а точнее с `oneof Value`.

`oneof` подразумевает, что полю `Value` будет задано одно из перечисленных значений, т.е. они не назначаются одновременно.

Таким образом, после генерации мы можем устанавливать поле `Value` так:

```
func Test_01(t *testing.T) {
    v1 := Update{ Value: &Update_Name{Name: "Value1"} }
    t.Logf("%#v\n", v1.Value)

    v2 := Update{ Value: &Update_Address{Address: "Value2"} }
    t.Logf("%#v\n", v2.Value)

    v3 := Update{ Value: &Update_Permission{Permission: int64(100)} }
    t.Logf("%#v\n", v3.Value)
}
```

Вывод в лог:

```
001.pb_test.go:7: &proto.Update_Name{Name:"Value1"}
001.pb_test.go:10: &proto.Update_Address{Address:"Value2"}
001.pb_test.go:13: &proto.Update_Permission{Permission:100}
```

Возможно вам нужно `Name`, `Address` и `Permission` объединить в одну структуру, чтобы передать разом, тогда сообщение можно объявить так:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;

message Update {
    message ValueType {
        string Name = 1;
        int64 Permission = 2;
        string Address = 3;
    }

    string AdminToken = 1;
    string Type = 2;
    string Hash = 3;
    ValueType Value = 4;
}
```

Соответственно создаём так:

```
func Test_01(t *testing.T) {
    v1 := Update{
        Value: &Update_ValueType{
            Name: "Value1",
            Address: "Value2",
            Permission: int64(100),
        },
    }

    t.Logf("%#v\n", v1.Value)
}
```

Вывод в лог:

```
001.pb_test.go:25: &proto.Update_ValueType{Name:"Value1", Permission:100, Address:"Value2"}
```